# Can’t understand the complex notation for trigonometric polynomials

Tags: calculus, analysis

A reference from “Introduction to calculus and analysis I”:

A compound vibration of the type
$$
S_n(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{v=1}^{n}(a_v\cos{vx}+b_v\sin{vx})
$$
(For brevity we have taken $\omega=1$) can be reduced to complex form by substituting

$$
\cos{vx} = \frac{1}{2}(e^{ivx}+e^{-ivx}),{\quad}\sin{vx}=-\frac{1}{2}i (e^{ivx}-e^{-ivx}).
$$

This expression then assumes the simpler form

$$
S_n(x)=\sum_{v=-n}^{n}{\alpha}_{v} e^{ivx},
$$

where the complex numbers ${\alpha}_{v}$ are related to the real numbers $a_0$, $a_v$, $b_v$ by the equations

$$
\alpha_v = \frac{1}{2}(a_v-ib_v), \\
\alpha_{-v} = \frac{1}{2}(a_v+ib_v),  \\
\alpha_{0}=\frac{1}{2}a_0.
$$

For $v=1,2,\dots,n$, and solving these relations for the $a_v$ and $b_v$, we find that

$$
a_v=\alpha_v+\alpha_{-v},\\
b_v=i(\alpha_v-\alpha_{-v}).
$$

(This case $v=0$ is included.)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Please explain it to me, thanks.

Comment: In your initial summation for $S_n(x)$, I believe the upper bound should be $n$ instead of $\infty$.

Comment: What's the question in detail?

Comment: @August You didn't specify what specifically you wanted to have explained, so I've tried to give a fairly general explanation of all of the steps involved in my answer. However, for any later questions of this type, if there's a specific part you're unsure about, please explicitly state what it is. That way, anybody answering won't spend time trying to explain what you already understand and can, instead, focus on what you don't understand.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, l’m sorry for the typo.

Comment: @JohnOmielan It’s my fault, I should post my initial derivation, give more details about my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $2$ complex forms for $\cos vx$ and $\sin vx$ you are given come from [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) which states

$$e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Using this gives that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{2}(e^{ivx}+e^{-ivx}) & = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(vx) + i\sin(vx) + \cos(-vx) + i\sin(-vx)) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(vx) + i\sin(vx) + \cos(vx) + -i\sin(vx)) \\
& = \frac{1}{2}(2\cos(vx)) \\
& = \cos(vx)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Similarly, you get

$$\sin(vx) = -\frac{1}{2}i (e^{ivx}-e^{-ivx}) \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

Substituting those $2$ forms into the summation, and collecting the $e^{ivx}$ and $e^{-ivx}$ terms, gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S_n(x) & = \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{v=1}^{n} \left(a_v\left(\frac{1}{2}(e^{ivx}+e^{-ivx})\right) + b_v\left(-\frac{1}{2}i (e^{ivx}-e^{-ivx})\right)\right) \\
& = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{v=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_v - ib_v)e^{ivx} + \frac{1}{2}(a_v + ib_v)e^{-ivx} \right) \\
& = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{v=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_v - ib_v)e^{ivx}\right) + \sum_{v=-n}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}(a_{-v} + ib_{-v})e^{ivx}\right) \\
& = \sum_{v=-n}^{n}{\alpha}_{v} e^{ivx}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

You have the initial constant term for $v = 0$ of $\alpha_0 = \frac{1}{2}a_0$. Also, wth the $e^{ivx}$ terms, you get $\frac{1}{2}(a_v-ib_v)$, which is the $\alpha_v$. With the $e^{-ivx}$ terms, you get the $\frac{1}{2}(a_v+ib_v)$, which is the $\alpha_{-v}$ (with the "$-$" for the fact the index is negative).

At the end, you can solve for the terms by adding the $\alpha_v = \frac{1}{2}(a_v-ib_v)$ and $\alpha_{-v} = \frac{1}{2}(a_v+ib_v)$ expressions to get $a_v=\alpha_v+\alpha_{-v}$. Also, subtracting the second from the first you get $ib_v = (-\alpha_v+\alpha_{-v}) \implies -b_v = i(-\alpha_v+\alpha_{-v}) \implies b_v = i(\alpha_v-\alpha_{-v})$, where I used $i^2 = -1$.

Finally, the $v = 0$ case is included because the $2$ equations give $a_0 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_0 = \frac{1}{2}a_0 + \frac{1}{2}a_0 = a_0$, and $b_0 = i(\alpha_0 - \alpha_0) = 0$, which is correct as there's no $b_0$ term being used.

Comment: From your derivation, $$S_n(x)=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{v=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{2}(a_v-ib_v)e^{ivx}\right)+ \sum_{v=-n}^{-1}\left( \frac{1}{2}(a_{-v}+ib_{-v})e^{Ivx} \right) \\ = \frac{a_0}{2} +  \sum_{v=1}^{n}(\alpha_{v}e^{ivx})+\sum_{v=-n}^{-1}(\alpha_{-v}e^{ivx})$$ is it right?

Comment: @August Not quite. The last summation should use $\alpha_v$ instead of $\alpha_{-v}$. The negative part is already in the index terms for $v$ going from $-n$ to $-1$. As you state it, the first term would be $\alpha_{-(-n)} = \alpha_{n}$, which duplicates the $1$st terms & is wrong. Note $\alpha_v = \frac{1}{2}(a_{-v} + ib_{-v})$ for $v = -n$ to $v = -1$ means, on change of $v$ from negative to positive, $\alpha_{-v} = \frac{1}{2}(a_{v} + ib_{v})$ for $v = 1$ to $v = n$. If you have trouble understanding this, just plug a few numbers in to confirm this works as I described.